# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find file field "file"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

Hi i am a beginner in rails and encounter some issues when i try to run rspec capybara test.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Upload Process", :type => :feature do

  it "Can upload a file" do
    visit new_document_path
    page.attach_file('file', '/Users/yaomin/Desktop/my_travel_pic/uploadtest.jpg', visible: false)
    click_button 'Upload'
    page.should have_content("Uploadtest")
  end
end
```

but i got the error

```
Failures:

  1) Upload Process Can upload a file
     Failure/Error: attach_file('file', '/Users/yaomin/Desktop/my_travel_pic/uploadtest.jpg', visible: false)

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find file field "file"
     # /Users/yaomin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:44:in `block in find'
     # /Users/yaomin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
     # /Users/yaomin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:33:in `find'
     # /Users/yaomin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:256:in `attach_file'
     # /Users/yaomin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:769:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # /Users/yaomin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/upload_test.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.40034 seconds (files took 1.99 seconds to load) 1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/upload_test.rb:5 # Upload Process Can upload a file
```

my view codes are

```
h1 Listing documents

table
  thead
    tr
      th
      th
      th

  tbody
    - @documents.each do |document|
      tr
        td = link_to 'Show', document
        td = link_to 'Edit', edit_document_path(document)
        td = link_to 'Destroy', document, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete

br

= link_to 'New Document', new_document_path
```

below is the new document view

```
h1 New document

= render 'form'

= link_to 'Back', documents_path

- if @document.folder
  = link_to "Back to '#{@document.folder.name}' Folder", browse_path(@document.folder)
- else
  = link_to "Back", root_url
```

and my form partial

```
= form_for @document do |f|
  - if @document.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      h2 = "#{pluralize(@document.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this document from being saved:"
      ul
        - @document.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          li = message
  = f.label :file
  = f.file_field :file
  - f.hidden_field :folder_id

  = f.submit "Upload"
```

For information, i can actually upload files manually but the upload test i run fails.

Thanks in advance for all your help :)

Comment: Could you show us your view code? And if you run `save_and_open_page` within `Can upload a file`, do you see the actual file field?

Comment: updated with views and partial form

Comment: save and open page works well

Comment: Do you actually see the `file` field on the new_document_path? And does the field have any hidden styling implemented by CSS?

Comment: Show the actual HTML for the part of the page with the file input - not the partial.  The first parameter to `attach_file` has to be the id, name, or text of the associated label - odds are none of those are 'file'.  Additionally you can't pass `visible: false` to attach_file since it still won't be able to interact with the control if it's visible.  If using a JS capable driver with a non-visible file input you can possible use the `make_visible: true` option

Comment: The button i click to upload a file is "Choose File" and to upload is "Upload"

they are auto name by carrierwave, acts as tree and dropzone.

Comment: i tried removing visible: false and also changing it make_visible: true. still same error

Comment: Suppose you have `<input id="upload_image" name="file_upload" type="file">` in your HTML. You can then do like so: `page.attach_file('file_upload', '/Users/yaomin/Desktop/my_travel_pic/uploadtest.jpg')`

Comment: i got 

<input type="file" name="document[file]" id="document_file">

Comment: ok - so it is what I guessed in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter passed to `attach_file` needs to be either the id, name, or associated labels text.  In your case that's probably not 'file'.  You state the associated label text is "Choose File" so probably something like

```
attach_file('Choose File', file_path)
```

is what you want (impossible to say exactly what the first parameter should be without the actual HTML).  Other things that may work would be

```
attach_file('document_file', file_path) # match the elements id
attach_file('document[file]', file_path) # match the elements name
```

but again, the first parameter could be slightly different, the HTML will show what they should be.

The other issue that is common with file inputs is that they may be hidden with CSS (made transparent, etc) in order to style the same across browsers.  If that is the case and you are using a JS capable driver you can use something like

```
attach_file('Choose File', file_path, make_visible: true)
```

which will attempt to make the field visible, set the file, and then restore the original CSS.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tried all your suggestions however my tests are still getting the same error.

Comment: @NYM Then you're either not on the page you think you are (does new_document_path require the user to be logged in?, etc),  or the html isn't what you think it is.  Look at `page.html` right before you try calling `attach_file` and add the form HTML to your question.